# Get access to atom values outside RecoilRoot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, recoiljs

In my project, i'm using "react-three/fiber" which is required to store all content inside "Canvas".
Also, for storing some states and share it with other modules in "Canvas" i'm using recoil's atom.

So, inside "RecoilRoot" everything works great, BUT i need to show data from atom in the "UI" component.

I can't put "RecoilRoot" out of "Canvas", so i tried to add a second "RecoilRoot". It kinda does the trick (now i can use "useRecoilValue" in "UI"), but it shows only default state of atom...

Here is how my "App.js" looks like:

```
function App() {


  return (

      <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
{/*Second RecoilRoot, outside the Canvas*/}
           <RecoilRoot>
            <Canvas shadows>
            <GameSettingsProvider>
{/*Main RecoilRoot with data*/}
              <RecoilRoot>
                <ObjectShow />
{/*Main RecoilRoot with data*/}
              </RecoilRoot>
              </GameSettingsProvider>
            </Canvas>
            <UI />
{/*Second RecoilRoot, outside the Canvas*/}
          </RecoilRoot>
      </Suspense>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Atom with data:

```
import {atom} from "recoil";
export const scoreState = atom({
    key: "score", // unique ID (with respect to other atoms/selectors)
    default: 0, // default value (aka initial value)
  });
```

UI module:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useRecoilValue } from 'recoil'
import { scoreState } from './gameState'


function UI() {

const score = useRecoilValue(scoreState);
  return (
    <div className='score-title'>
        <h1 className='score-title__text'>
            Score: {score}
        </h1>
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default UI
```

So, how can i use atom values outside "RecoilRoot" or, at least, share from nested one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 different renders DOM and Canvas.

Couldn't find any workarounds to transfer states via Recoil, so i used Zustand state manager for score state.
It can transfer states even between renders!

Work like a charm.